# Conditionally returning a React component to satisfy a Suspense fallback

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-suspense

Normally when I'm returning a component (I'm using nextjs 13) that relies on fetched data, I conditionally render elements to ensure values are available:

**TableComponent:**

```
export const Table = ({ ...props }) => {

    const [tableEvents, setTableEvents] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchAndSetTableEvents();
    }, []);


    async function fetchAndSetTableEvents() {
        const fetchedEvents = await fetch(* url and params here *)
        if (fetchedEvents && fetchedEvents) {
            setTableEvents(fetchedEvents);
        } else {
            setTableEvents(null);
        }
    }

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <div>
                {tableEvents ? tableEvents[0].title : null}
            </div>
        </React.Fragment>
    )


};
```

If I try and load TableComponent from a parent component using **Suspense**, it loads but doesn't show the fallback before it's loaded:

```
<Suspense fallback={<div>Loading Message...</div>}>
    <TableComponent />
</Suspense>
```

However, if I remove the conditional rendering in **TableComponent** and just specify the variable, the fallback shows correctly while it's attempting to load the component:

```
return (
    <React.Fragment>
        <div>
            {tableEvents[0].title}
        </div>
    </React.Fragment>
)
```

But it ultimately fails to load the component as **tableEvents** is initially null and will vary on each fetch so it cannot have a predictable key.

The [React docs](https://17.reactjs.org/docs/concurrent-mode-suspense.html#what-is-suspense-exactly) for Suspense just show a simple example like this.

Conditionally returning the render also returns the component ok but fails to show the suspense fallback

```
if (tableEvents) {
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <div>
                {tableEvents[0].event_title}
            </div>
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}
```

#### Question

How do I fetch and return values in a component, that may or may not exist, *that satisfy the criteria for a Suspense fallback to show when loading*. I'm assuming it relies on a Promise in a way that I'm blocking but can't find a way around.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## TL;DR

For `Suspense` to be triggered, one of the children must `throw` a `Promise`. This feature is more aimed at library developers but you could still try implementing something for yourself.

## Pseudocode

The basic idea is pretty simple, here's the pseudo-code

```js
function ComponentWithLoad() {
  const promise = fetch('/url') // create a promise

  if (promise.pending) { // as long as it's not resolved
    throw promise // throw the promise
  }

  // otherwise, promise is resolved, it's a normal component
  return (
    <p>{promise.data}</p>
  )
}
```

When a `Suspense` boundary is thrown a `Promise` it will await it, and re-render the component when the promise resolves. That's all.

## Problem

Except that now we have 2 issues:

- we need to be able to get the content of our promise without async/await since that's not allowed in react outside of "Framework Land"
- upon re-render, `fetch` will actually create a *new* promise, which will be thrown again, and we'll be looping forever...

The solution to both of these issues is to find a way to store the promise outside of the `Suspense` boundary (and in most likelihood, outside of react entirely).

## Solution

### Obtain promise status without `async`

First, let's write a wrapper around any promise that will allow us to get either its status (pending, resolved, rejected) or its resolved data.

```js
const promises = new WeakMap()
function wrapPromise(promise) {
  const meta = promises.get(promise) || {}

  // for any new promise
  if (!meta.status) {
    meta.status = 'pending' // set it as pending
    promise.then((data) => { // when resolved, store the data
      meta.status = 'resolved'
      meta.data = data
    })
    promise.catch((error) => { // when rejected store the error
      meta.status = 'rejected'
      meta.error = error
    })
    promises.set(promise, meta)
  }

  if (meta.status === 'pending') { // if still pending, throw promise to Suspense
    throw promise
  }
  if (meta.status === 'error') { // if error, throw error to ErrorBoundary
    throw new Error(meta.error)
  }

  return meta.data // otherwise, return resolved data
}
```

With this function called on every render, we'll be able to get the promise's data without any `async`. It's then React `Suspense`'s job to re-render when needed. That what it does.

### Maintain a constant reference to `Promise`

Then we only need to store our promise outside of the `Suspense` boundary. The most simple example of this would be to declare it in the parent, but the ideal solution (to avoid creating a new promise when the parent itself re-renders) would be to store it outside of react itself.

```
export default function App() {

  // create a promise *outside* of the Suspense boundary
  const promise = fetch('/url').then(r => r.json())

  // Suspense will try to render its children, if rendering throws a promise, it'll try again when that promise resolves
  return (
    <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
      {/* we pass the promise to our suspended component so it's always the same `Promise` every time it re-renders */}
      <ComponentWithLoad promise={promise} />
    </Suspense>
  )
}

function ComponentWithLoad({promise}) {
  // using the wrapper we declared above, it will
  //  - throw a Promise if it's still pending
  //  - return synchronously the result of our promise otherwise
  const data = wrapPromise(promise)

  // we now have access to our fetched data without ever using `async`
  return <p>{data}</p>
}
```

## Some more details

- `WeakMap` is pretty ideal to map between a `promise` and some metadata about this promise (status, returned data, ...) because as soon as the `promise` itself is not referenced anywhere, the metadata is made available for garbage collection
- While a component is "under suspense" (meaning any component in the render tree from it to the next `Suspense` boundary throws a promise), it will be unmounted by react after each "attempt" at rendering. This means that you cannot use a `useState` or a `useRef` to hold the promise or its status.
- unless you are writing an opinionated library (like tanstack-query for example), it's almost impossible to have a generally valid way of storing promises. It's entirely dependant on your application's behavior. It might be as simple as having a `Map` between endpoints and the `Promise` fetching that endpoint, and only grows in complexity from there with refetches, cache-control, headers, request params... This is why my example only creates a simple promise once.

## Answer to the question

When using `Suspense`, none of the tree inside of the Suspense node will be rendered while any of it still throws a Promise. If you need to render something in the meantime, that's what the `fallback` prop is for.

It does require us to change the way we think about the segmentation of our components

- if you want your fallback to share some of the structure / data / css with the suspended component
- if you want to avoid a waterfall of loading components preventing a big render tree from displaying anything at all

Comment: This is such an insightful answer - I have a path to follow to a solution and I'm learning a lot of the why along the way. I really appreciate the time you put into it

Answer (score 0):

Just add `async` to the component.

Component:

```
const ListProducts = async ({ data }: { data: any }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        {data.children.map((item: any) => (
          <li key={item.data.id} className="p-2 bg-slate-400 my-1">
            {item.data.title}
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ListProducts;
```

Parent component or Page:

```
<Suspense
  key={searchParams.limit}
  fallback={
    <div className="flex items-center justify-center h-[50vh] bg-black text-white text-4xl rounded-2xl">
      Loading...
    </div>
      }
    >
    <ListProducts data={data} />
</Suspense>
```